# Polymer 2 dar estilo a un nodo hijo desde una hoja de estilo

Tags: css, polymer

Tengo un elemento llamado `<mi-curso>` con su propio estilo definido en la etiqueta `<style>` dentro de la definición `<dom-module>` y **no quiero editar o alterar el archivo de definición del elemento** es una dependencia externa a mi proyecto.

El elemento `<mi-curso>` tiene un `<div>` definido dentro de la etiqueta `<template>` tal y como se muestra a continuación.

Ejemplo:

```html
<dom-module id="mi-curso">
    <template>
        <style>
        
          ::host {
            padding: 5px;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
          }
          
          div#progress {
            height: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            background: red;
          }        
        </style>
        <h1>This is my custom course element</h1>
        <div id="progress"></div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
      class MyCourse extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() {
          return 'mi-curso';
        }
      }
      
      window.customElements.define(MyCourse.is, MyCourse);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Quiero hacer el `div#progress` verde con `"background: green;"` (es rojo por defecto) via una hoja de estilos externa que se carga en la misma página que se añade y usa este elemento personalizado.

Intenté:

```
mi-curso div#progress {
   background: green;
}
```

Pero no funciona, el `div` `progreso` sigue rojo. Parece que no hay forma de darle estilo al shadow dom desde fuera del propio elemento. También he intentado `mi-curso::content div#progress`, sin resultado (`/deep/` y `::shadow` están deprecados) Anteriormente en Polymer 1.x esto lo lograba con `::shadow`.

¿Alguien puede ayudar? Gracias.

Comment: This is spanish site. Please translate it or migrate to stackoverflow.com

Comment: Done, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: ¿No sería mejor [usar variables css y modificarlas dinámicamente](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/start/first-element/step-5) en cada componente?

Comment: Si, por supuesto que es mejor. Pero depende que el que ha diseñado el elemento haya incorporado esas variables. Se trata de reutilizar código / elementos publicados en webcomponents sin modificarlos para poder actualizarlos (eliminar bugs etc)